# Enabling file editing on a file stored on a server through custom routes and POST/GET Requests

Tags: server, file-systems, users

I am creating a platform which allows multiple users to edit a file simultaneously and I was wondering if using a web server with routes could be the correct architecture for this goal. I am trying to achieve something similar to Figma or Google Docs, where they allow multiple users to edit a single file concurrently.

My current idea is to have a server with an file system for each group of user (through a virtual machine or a container). Then I could have a route for editing a file (like for example
/edit) where, with a `POST` request having the file path and a JSON for the edit as the parameters, an user can "append" an edit to a file. For example, a request could be like this:

```
{
    "path": "/files/file1.txt",
    "edit": {
        "type": "insert",
        "pos": 0,
        "data": "Hello, world!"
    }
}
```

In this way, I could also check if an user has the permissions necessary to edit the file by validating the request with a guard to the edit route through an auth provider like auth0.

Additionally, for reading the files, I was thinking of similarly doing an initial `GET` request for the file when an user initially opens it and then automatically sending any edit to the file to users which have the file open.

I am not sure however if using plain routes and simple POST/GET request is the correct way of dealing with this issue.

I am new to backend development so I am worried I could be re-inventing the wheel (and a bad one at that) when a framework for this kind of app already exists. However, I tried looking online but I could not find anything that matches what I am trying to achieve.

Is this a valid/canonical approach for achieving edits to a file on a server?

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you are trying to solve? Asking "how to allow multiple users to edit a file" is way too broad for this community.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question. I hope is clearer now. the part I am stuck on is whether using plain POST/GET requests and routes is the canonical way of achieving file edits on a remote file. I removed the multi-user part as it is not the subject of the question and I initially added it to provide more context to the question.

Comment: The `path` attribute won't be sufficient. You will also need a serial, timestamp, hash, or similar to identify each specific revision. Using GET to read & render the document is fine. For mutation there's more than one web [verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch) that may be relevant.